# Iterate through geodataframes and overlay them to create a single output

Tags: python, gis, geospatial, geopandas

I am attempting to iterate through dissolved_result and overlay them using how='intersection' to create a single output file that represents all of the input dissolved_results. I am struggling with how best to do that, this is what I have so far and the error I get.

All inputs are polygons/multipolygons.

I would really really appreciate any help!

```
def usable(gdf, feature_gdf, zoom_level, shuffle_tiles=False):

    feature_gdf = gpd.read_file(inshp)
    feature_gdf = feature_gdf.to_crs(epsg=5070)   
    intermediate_result = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
  
    for index, row in gdf.iterrows(): 
        geometry = row['geometry']
        tiles = list_tiles(geometry, zoom=zoom_level, shuf=shuffle_tiles)
         
        for tile in tiles:
            tile_bounds = mercantile.bounds(*tile)
            tile_box = gpd.GeoSeries([box(*tile_bounds)], crs=gdf.crs)
            tile_box = tile_box.to_crs(epsg=5070)       
                 
            if feature_gdf.intersects(tile_box.unary_union).any():
                intersected_features = feature_gdf[feature_gdf.intersects(tile_box.unary_union)]
                buffered_features = intersected_features.copy()
                buffered_features['geometry'] = buffered_features.buffer(buffer_distance)
                tile_minus_buffered = tile_box.difference(buffered_features.unary_union)
                tile_buffer = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=tile_minus_buffered, crs=tile_box.crs)
                intermediate_result = pd.concat([intermediate_result, tile_buffer], ignore_index=True)
                
            else:
                tile_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=tile_box, crs=tile_box.crs)
                intermediate_result = pd.concat([intermediate_result, tile_gdf], ignore_index=True)

        # save_file(intermediate_result, 'result')
    
    dissolved_result = intermediate_result.dissolve()
    
    final_result = gpd.GeoDataFrame()

    for index, row in dissolved_result.iterrows():
        result = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[row['geometry']], crs=dissolved_result.crs)   
        final_result = gpd.overlay(final_result, result, how='intersection')
    print(final_result.head())
```

error:

`AttributeError: The CRS attribute of a GeoDataFrame without an active geometry column is not defined. Use GeoDataFrame.set_geometry to set the active geometry column.`